# 2003 Chevy Cavalier rear popcorn popping noise

Tags: chevrolet

A couple weeks ago I started noticing a popcorn popping noise coming from the rear of my Cavalier every time I'm on the highway going around 70. My car drives very smooth and there's no vibrations or anything. For some reason every time a car gets behind me they end up slowing way down to where it's like they don't want to be behind me.  I took it into the shop and a guy did a sit in where I drove my car and he came with me trying to figure this out.  He told me nothing seems to be wrong that he didn't have the slightest clue what is wrong.  What could possibly be wrong with it anyone having the same issues?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!  Does it happen only when going 70 mph, or also at slower speeds?  Does the noise change as the engine revs?

Comment: No noise at coming to a stop and accelerating. The noise is only noticeable on the highway really.

Comment: If the noise is speed related, have you checked all your tires for rocks embedded into the tread and/or small metallic objects?